# can't run sql script in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

there is problem in my mysql workbnech application , this is eror always show every i want to run sql script , anyone know about this ?
[image]

Comment: Close the file that and then try again, since same file you are trying to access

Answer (score 0):

Use the free tool [Opened Files View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) to discover which process is locking your temp files (antivirus, shell, and so on...).